Тянутся "шлейфы" за окнами внутри MDI-интерфейса при их перемещении
Ради более симпатичного внешнего вида дочерних окон отключил у них "рамку". Теперь перемещением окна управляет следующий код, предварительно запоминая координаты "клика":
private void MoveDocument(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Left += e.X - _mouseClickPoint.X;
    this.Top += e.Y - _mouseClickPoint.Y;
}

Включение двойной буферизации ни для дочерней, ни для главной формы не помогает. Со стандартной рамкой у окон такой проблемы не наблюдается.




Попробуйте this.Invalidate(), не поможет - добавьте Update, не поможет - попробуйте Refresh. Вдруг да поможет )  Возможно, всё это нужно делать вообще с родительской формой.

Спасибо за ответ! Уже пробовал, и с родительской формой, и с дочерней - само по себе не работает, только слегка снижает эффект. Попробовал только что другой вариант - перегрузил метод OnPaint и перемещал форму в нем. Это помогло, но теперь верхняя панель перемещаемой дочерней формы (та, что синяя) оставляет шлейфы на других формах при перемещении над ними.

А базовый OnPaint не забываете там вызывать? Блин, давно всё это было, я уже очень смутно помню, как в вин формах правильно всё делать. Тем более в MDI.

Да, разумеется. Сначала base.OnPaint, а после него перемещение формы в новую точку. P.S. если не работать с MDI в WinForms, то с чем вообще там работать?))

Я наверное с модальными окнами спутал )  MDI норм

@JamesBond с нормальным многооконным интерфейсом, как во всех современных программах?

А при чём тут вообще OnPaint? Вроде должно быть и без него хорошо?

@Qwertiy препод курса, по которому я учусь, говорил, что во избежание разнообразных глюков (вроде пропадания изображения после сворачивания и разворачивания окна) все рисование должно выполняться в методе Paint, т.к. этот метод и отвечает за отрисовку всего приложения.

Я тоже поддержу вопрос "при чем тут OnPaint", если речь идет о перетаскивании. Разве перетаскивание происходит не в MousMove? Если в MouseMove - то откуда берем аргумент для OnPaint?

Видимо пора просить показать код перетаскивания :-)

@Uranus все просто. В MouseMove мы обновляем координаты точки, в которую следует переместить форму (точка вычисляется из координат курсора). Затем вызываем Invalidate(), и уже в методе OnPaint перемещаем форму в эту точку.

@JamesBond, рисование в OnPaint - это верно. Но какое отношение перетаскивание имеет к рисованию? Кажется, что система должна сама обрабатывать перетаскивание и ему лишние костыли не нужны?

@Qwertiy должна-то должна, да не обрабатывает, как видите. Еще при добавлении каждой новой дочерней формы наблюдаются глюки в виде появления окна в точке, в которой оно появилось бы если бы начальная позиция не обрабатывалась, а затем уже перемещается в точку, которую я указал как стартовую. У меня такое чувство, что мой код как-то конфликтует с кодом дизайнера - в дизайнере задана стартовая позиция формы, у меня в кострукторе тоже. А менять дизайнер руками вроде как нельзя... И с размером форм то же самое

попробуйте всё-таки двигать форму в событии MouseMove, чтобы не мешать отрисовке. У меня такой подход сработал без глюков

Кстати, да. Что за событие такое MoveDocument? Что-то не гуглится у меня такое. Куда это событие навешено? Голосую за обработку движения в MouseMove, как выше написали )

@CrazyElf это не событие, а обработчик для события MouseMove)) Это класс текстового документа, поэтому и методы называются соответственно.

А, ну да, я мог бы догадаться по MouseEventArgs. Ну не знаю тогда куда дальше двигаться )

@CrazyElf покопаюсь еще завтра, может допишу что-то, если новая информация появится. Странная ситуация. Было бы интересно посмотреть, как логика перемещения окон реализована в самом WinForms, при перемещении за стандартную рамку. Может там используется метод, который можно перегрузить...

Нашел решение с использованием методов библиотеки "user32.dll":
public static class WindowMovementManager
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private const int Msg = 0xA1; // Код сообщения, определяющий действие. Для перетаскивания окна используется WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN (значение 0xA1), что указывает системе начать обработку "нажатия" на неклиентскую (заголовок) часть окна.

    private const int wParam = 0x2; // Дополнительная информация о сообщении. В данном случае это значение HTCAPTION (0x2), чтобы указать системе, что нужно двигать окно за область заголовка, независимо от того, откуда идет перетаскивание.

    public static void Move(Form form)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(form.Handle, Msg, wParam, 0);
    }
}

Для упрощения использования сделал класс статическим. По желанию можно сделать его методом расширения для класса Form, только будет нужно другое имя.
Итого - для перемещения окна нам нужно вызвать данный метод в обработчике события MouseDown (именно в нем - это важно) у интересующего нас компонента, передав ему ссылку на данную форму. Самому методу от формы нужен только дескриптор, так что этот момент можно поменять если нужно.
Таким образом, вызывая данный метод в обработчике события MouseDown для интересующего нас контрола, мы фактически будем имитировать перемещение окна за рамку.
